# IRepositoy.InsertOrUpdateAsync throwing concurrency exception

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

I was creating a content managment system  on ABP using entityframework and .net core. I am getting concurrency exccetion when using InsertOrUpdateAsync. I do not have any data in my table.

Please find the Model used to create table.

```
   [Table("CMSContents")]
   public class CMSContent:Entity<int>
   {
       public const int MAXTITLELENGHT = 128;

       public const int MAXCONTENTLENGTH = 10000;

       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public override int Id { get; set; }
       /// <summary>
       /// The title of the content.
       /// </summary>
       [Required]
       [StringLength(MAXTITLELENGHT)]
       public virtual string PageName { get;  set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// The Cms Content
       /// </summary>
       public virtual  string PageContent { get; set; }

       protected CMSContent()
       {

       }

       public static CMSContent CreateContent(int id,string title ,string contents)
       {
           var @content = new CMSContent
           {
               Id =  id, 
               PageName = title,
               PageContent = contents
           };

           return @content;
       }
   }
}
```

Below is the Application service used to call the repository.

```
public async Task<CMSContent> InsertOrUpdateCMSContent(CreateContentInput input)
        {
            var @content = CMSContent.CreateContent(input.Id,input.PageName, input.PageContent);
            return await _contentManager.InsertOrUpdateAsync(@content);
        }
```

Exception while calling this API from Swagger,

Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
Abp.Domain.Uow.AbpDbConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions. ---> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32 commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagationAsync(Int32 commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpDbContext.cs:line 224
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpDbContext.cs:line 230
   at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroCommonDbContext`3.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\Zero\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs:line 170
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.SaveChangesInDbContextAsync(DbContext dbContext) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 167
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 68
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.CompleteUowAsync() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 83
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.CompleteAsync() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkBase.cs:line 273
   at Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Uow.AbpUowActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.AspNetCore\AspNetCore\Mvc\Uow\AbpUowActionFilter.cs:line 51
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)

Comment: Judging by some Google results, you probably need to wrap your statements within a unit of work.

Comment: You should not set `Id` since it is `DatabaseGenerated`.

Comment: @aaron As the InsertOrUpdate works based on id value, should it be provided on the statement?

Comment: @poke Could you give me code sample on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work

Comment: @django what do you mean by *should it be provided on the statement?*

Comment: @poke As per the comments for this method , It  inserts or updates  the entity based on the ID value.

Comment: @poke I tried the following code to implement Unit of work but error still persists.

'''
        [Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWork]

        public async Task<CMSContent> InsertOrUpdateAsync(CMSContent content)
        {
            return await _contentRepository.InsertOrUpdateAsync(@content);
        }

Comment: @django You want to insert, not update, right?

Comment: @aaron I believe the method insertorupdate will insert /update the entity based on the id value.I hoping this method will insert value if no value with id exists else update. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @django No, it inserts if `Id` is not set.

Comment: @aaron if id is not set, how it will update the data? based on the other values?

Comment: @django As mentioned, if `Id` is not set, then it inserts.

Comment: @aaron So before we calling insertorupdate, should we check if the id exists there on DB and set/not set id based on this?

Comment: @django No, why did you set `Id` for new entity?

Comment: @aaron I tried the following .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following approach to make it work, posting as an answer since comment wont allow this many characters.

> ```
>       public async Task<CMSContent> InsertOrUpdateCMSContent(CreateContentInput input)
>     {
>         var exists = await _contentRepository
>             .GetAll()
>             .AnyAsync(e => e.Id == input.Id);
>         if (!exists)
>         {
>            var @content = CMSContent.CreateContent(input.PageName, input.PageContent);
>             return await _contentRepository.InsertAsync(@content);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             var @content = CMSContent.CreateContent(input.Id, input.PageName, input.PageContent);
>             return await _contentRepository.UpdateAsync(@content);
>         }            
>     }
> ```

Comment: So does it work? Why did you set `Id` for new entity?

Comment: @aaron I was thinking that the insertorupdate method will insert the record by checking the id value on DB. So to check that, I populated the ID.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You populate the `Id` with a random number?